# Handlebars yield error with '/:username' param

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router

I set up my router so that if someone types in sitename.com/:username, it goes directly to that users page. But for some reason, when I attempt to do this I sometimes get redirected to my home page and get this error in the console.

```
Sorry, couldn't find the main yield. Did you define it in one of the rendered templates like this: {{yield}}?
```

It's even more strange because I would say 60% of the time it loads fine and there are no issues. Does anyone familiar with Meteor, Handlebars, and the Iron-Router package know about this or can help?

If you need more code let me know.

Here is the routing. I added the wait() call at the end to see if that would help. It seems to have helped a bit but the error still occurs.

```
this.route('userPosts', {
    path: '/:username',
    layoutTemplate: 'insideLayout',
    template: 'userPosts',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'insideNavigationList': {to: 'list'},
        'brandContainer': {to: 'brand'},
        'postsPageOptions': {to: 'pageOptions'}
    },
    waitOn: function () {
            return [Meteor.subscribe('userData'), Meteor.subscribe('selectedUser', this.params.username), Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.params.username)];
    },
    data: function () {
        return Meteor.users.findOne({username: this.params.username}) && Session.set('selectedUserId', Meteor.users.findOne({username: this.params.username})._id)
    },
    before: function () {
        if (!Meteor.user()) {
            this.redirect('/login')
        }
        this.subscribe('selectedUser', this.params.username).wait();
            this.ready();
    }

});
```

Comment: what does your dynamic route looks like, please upload the code

Comment: does username have anything to do with a subscription that may or may not have been ready yet?